# Trying to upload a php website to a web server

Tags: php, dreamweaver

When making a php web site in dream weaver, does the site have to have htdocs folder ?

The problem I have is I have a domain www.whatever.com.
Once I created the index.php in dreamweaver, I hit the put button and it uploads just fine.
So the connection to my website from dreamweaver works.

But when I got to the website www.whatever.com , it shows an apache test page where I want the index.php to show.

Comment: You put your files in whatever your public folder is called on your web host, could be public, public_html, www or nothing.

Comment: Then the problem is not on your local server(htdocs folder). It is on your hosting or how you upload the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is "no". Every website functions differently and having a htdocs folder is not a requirement by any means.

I suggest trying to upload index.php to the root directory (folder). The "root" is basically the top level folder that you have access to on your hosting account. Then, if that doesn't work, keep trying folders until it does work. As other people suggested, the correct folder can be called "public", "public_html", "www" or something else.

Just be sure you remember where it is located for for future reference. And don't leave a bunch of index.php files scattered in various locations on your server or it could create problems on your website in the future.